# Avoid ImageView hover state inside Listview if List Item is pressed

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a `ImageView` inside `listview` in left most position.This `imageView` and `listView` has all states (pressed ,selected,focused,normal).If I click `ListView` but not `ImageView` then in some devices the hover state(selected,focused,pressed) of `ImageView` is called.
So I want to know how to avoid this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the steps to resolve this issue. Create a class called `NoParentPressImageView` with the following code:

```
public class NoParentPressImageView extends ImageView {

    public NoParentPressImageView(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
        this.setFocusable(false);
    }

    public NoParentPressImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.setFocusable(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void setPressed(boolean pressed) {
        // If the parent is pressed, do not set to pressed.
        if (pressed && ((View) getParent()).isPressed()) {
            return;
        }
        super.setPressed(pressed);
    }
}
```

Note that the `setFocusable(false)` in the constructor has the same effect as adding `android:focusable="false"` to the `xml` layout document. This allows the `ListView` rows to be clickable. The `onPressed` override method solves the problem that you mention here, namely press events in the `ListView` (parent) rippling through to the `ImageView` (child).

Once you have this class defined, you can replace `ImageView` in your `xml` layout with `com.MYCOMPANY.MYAPP.NoParentPressImageView`.  Compile and run, and the `ListView` should now behave as you expect, with the `ImageView` pressed events only being triggered when you actually click on the image and not when you click elsewhere in the row.

Comment: Its realy nice.Dont forget to add setFocusable(false) .

Answer (score -1):

Try adding `android:focusable="false"` to the `ImageView` in your layout file.