# How to customize a list in android?

Tags: android, list, adapter

i'am using a list in my main activity

and i don't want to use android list , i want to create my own list ,already i created my custom Adapter that enables me to use images and text in any row of list but i want to disable the divider of the list and the hover mode

it's mean that i don't want to have something like this pic

it is not my project screenshot

[image]

thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

related with [Avoid ImageView hover state inside Listview if List Item is pressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14869236/avoid-imageview-hover-state-inside-listview-if-list-item-is-pressed)
you can use :

set empty  background

```
android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
```

or

```
android:cacheColorHint = "#00000000"
```

to remove divider between items in the list use :

```
myListview.setDivider(null);
```

or XML:

```
android:divider="@null"
android:dividerHeight="0dp"
```

Answer (score 1):

in your adapter, override the method `isEnabled(int position)` and have it return false for this item.

Comment: if i could select two answer as accepted this answer was one of them ,my question has to part and this is the answer of disabling the hover mode

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have your own CustomListAdapter, do the following in your `onCreate()` method:

```
ListView list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list); //or whatever the id of your listview is

// Getting adapter by passing xml data ArrayList
YourCustomAdapter adapter = new YourCustomAdapter(this, listDataToBeDisplayed);
list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try code below to disable the highlight, you may change the text color as well

```
ListView.setSelector(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
```